# Definition of a new Event for a UserDefined control or common controls in c#

Tags: c#

I want to define a new event for a general button control or any other my defined controls in c#. how can do it?

Comment: You might also want to read answers to similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464784/what-is-the-syntax-to-declare-an-event-in-c

Comment: Or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448487/how-to-dispatch-events-in-c/2448530#2448530).

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass from the button control and define a new event.

Use the [`event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx) keyword in your class, as seen in the example on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Hope. I understant what you really mean, cause "programming skills" tag confuse me.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739.aspx) you can find a short but vey good example of how to do it.

If this is not what you're asking for, please explain better.

Comment: @oded thanks, writing from mobile, no way here to format answer.

Answer (score 0):

First derive a class from [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) or use a existing derived-class from it if you want to give additional infos to the eventhandler.

Than you define a event in your control:

```
    public event EventHandler<yourEventClass> MyEventName;
```

or

```
    public event EventHandler MyEventName;
```

if you don't want additional infos.

Now you should define a private method to invoke the event from your code (I don't like this public but if you need to feel free to change):

```
    private void InvokeMyEvent( ... parameter for your additional infos ...)
    {
       var handler = MyEventName;
       if (handler == null) return;

       handler(this, new MyEventArgs(...parameters...); // if you have additional parameters
       handler(this, EventArgs.Empty); // if you don't want additional parameters
    }
```

Comment: You 2nd code snipped looks like the first one.

Comment: thanks .. allways get in trouble with < and >

Comment: Now there is a ; missing after the &lt ;-) Should be public event EventHandler&lt;yourEventClass> MyEventName;   But I cannot change it, because SO only allows changes containing more than 6 non-whitespace characters :(